# Check file size is larger than 1.6GB

Tags: bash

I have the following step in my Bash code which checks to see if a file is bigger than 1.6GB:

```
#!/bin/sh

SIZE_THRESHOLD=1717986918

if [[ $(find /home/methuselah/file -type f -size +${SIZE_THRESHOLD}c 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
  somecmdbecausefileisbigger
else
  somecmdbecausefileissmaller
fi
```

The command `somecmdbecausefileisbigger` is never triggered even when the file size is greater than 1.6GB. Why is this?

Comment: Don't use `#!/bin/sh` if you are using `bash` extensions like `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: Working as expected here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your `find` command doesn't work, but I do know a simpler way to do this:

```
if [ $(stat -f %z /home/methuselah/file) -gt ${SIZE_THRESHOLD} ]; then
```

Though unfortunately you have to replace `-f %z` with `-c %s` on Linux (the former works on BSD and MacOS).

Answer (score 1):

Just use `stat` (note that your version of `stat` may differ; check your man page for details):

```
if [ "$(stat -c '%s' /home/methuselah/file)" -gt "$SIZE_THRESHOLD" ]; then
```